# Iterating over IEnumerable, special casing last element

Tags: c#, ienumerable, stringbuilder

I'm building a string based on an `IEnumerable`, and doing something like this:

```
public string BuildString()
{
    var enumerable = GetEnumerableFromSomewhere(); // actually an in parameter,
                                                   // but this way you don't have to care
                                                   // about the type :)

    var interestingParts = enumerable.Select(v => v.TheInterestingStuff).ToArray();

    stringBuilder.Append("This is it: ");

    foreach(var part in interestingParts)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendPart(part);

        if (part != interestingParts.Last())
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(", ");
        }
    }
}

private static void AppendPart(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, InterestingPart part)
{
    stringBuilder.Append("[");
    stringBuilder.Append(part.Something");
    stringBuilder.Append("]");

    if (someCondition(part)) 
    {
         // this is in reality done in another extension method,
         // similar to the else clause
         stringBuilder.Append(" = @");
         stringBuilder.Append(part.SomethingElse");
    }
    else
    {
         // this is also an extension method, similar to this one
         // it casts the part to an IEnumerable, and iterates over
         // it in much the same way as the outer method.
         stringBuilder.AppendInFilter(part);
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely happy with this idiom, but I'm struggling to formulate something more succinct.

This is, of course, part of a larger string building operation (where there are several blocks similar to this one, as well as other stuff in between) - otherwise I'd probably drop the `StringBuilder` and use `string.Join(", ", ...)` directly.

My closest attempt at simplifying the above, though, is constructs like this for each iterator:

```
stringBuilder.Append(string.Join(", ", propertyNames.Select(prop => "[" + prop + "]")));
```

but here I'm still concatenating strings with `+`, which makes it feel like the `StringBuilder` doesn't really contribute much.

How could I simplify this code, while keeping it efficient?

Comment: You can use `prop => $"[{prop}]"` or `prop => string.Format("[{0}]", prop)`

Comment: If your goal is to reduce memory allocations, then you can't really simplify this code, this is how the StringBuilder works. If the content of the `foreach` loop is much bigger than you should split it into small methods for readability, but that's about all you can do

Answer (score 2):

You can replace this:

```
string.Join(", ", propertyNames.Select(prop => "[" + prop + "]"))
```

With c# 6 string interpolation:

```
string.Join(", ", propertyNames.Select(prop => $"[{prop}]"))
```

In both cases the difference is **semantic only** and it doesn't really matter. String concatenation like in your case in the select isn't a problem. The compiler still creates only 1 new string for it (and not 4, one for each segment and a 4th for the joint string).

Putting it all together:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", enumerable.Select(v => $"[{v.TheInterestingStuff}]"));
```

---

Because body of `foreach` is more complex that to fit in a String Interpolation scope you can just remove the last N characters of the string once calculated, as KooKiz suggested.

```
string separator = ", ";
foreach(var part in interestingParts)
{
    stringBuilder.Append("[");
    stringBuilder.Append(part);
    stringBuilder.Append("]");

    if (someCondition(part)) 
    {
        // Append more stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // Append other thingd
    }
    stringBuilder.Append(separator);
}
stringBuilder.Length = stringBuilder.Lenth - separator;
```

*In any case I think that for better encapsulation the content of the loop's scope should sit in a separate function that will receive a `part` and the `separator` and will return the output string. It can also be an extension method for `StringBuilder` as suggested by user734028*

Comment: That's still one string created where there could be zero. In most cases it wouldn't matter, but OP's requirements are unclear

Comment: Check with string.IsNullOrEmpty or string.IsNullOrWhitespace and you can calculate capacity to reduce memory allocations in StringBuilder

Comment: I know that my strings will never be null, so that's a non-issue. However, the body is usually too complex to replace with string interpolation.

Comment: @TomasLycken - May you please show a more complex version of the body? So I can adjust my answer?

Comment: String interpolation uses `String.Format` in background, where `string.Format` uses cached instance of `StringBuilder` in background.

Comment: @GiladGreen: See my edit to the question. I made the examples much more like my real case - I hope it helps illustrate the complexity.

Comment: `"[" + prop + "]"` is not identical to `$"[{prop}]"`

Answer (score 0):

**Aggregate** solution:

```
var answer = interestingParts.Select(v => "[" + v + "]").Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```

**Serialization** solution:

```
var temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(interestingParts.Select(x => new[] { x }));
var answer = temp.Substring(1, temp.Length - 2).Replace(",", ", ");
```

Comment: I wish people stopped using `Aggregate` for concatenation (damn you Resharper). It's not more readable than `string.Join` and is **way** less efficient

Comment: I love Aggregate, for purposes where it's appropriate. This isn't one of them :)

Comment: @KooKiz, Resharper? You think it is impossible to use Aggregate without it's help?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Haha no, just that I've seen many developers blindly replace a loop by an Aggregate without thinking, just because Resharper suggested it, even though they would never have considered it

Answer (score 0):

Use `Aggregate` extension method with `StringBuilder`.
Will be more efficiently then concatenate strings if your collection are big

```
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        list.Aggregate(builder, (sb, person) =>
        {
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append("[");
            sb.Append(person.Name);
            sb.Append("]");
            return sb;
        });
        builder.Remove(0, 1); // Remove first comma
```

As pure `foreach` is always more efficient then `LINQ` then just change logic for delimeter comma

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var part in enumerable.Select(v => v.TheInterestingStuff))
{
    builder.Append(", ");
    builder.Append("[");
    builder.Append(part);
    builder.Append("]");
}

builder.Remove(0, 2); //Remove first comma and space
```

Comment: How is this better than using a for loop and not special-casing the last element?

Comment: Only because you don't use special-casing for last element. One operation less per loop

Comment: @Fabio When writing an algorithm to trim a separator, it's more efficient to put the separator at the end. At the beginning, the StringBuilder needs to reallocate the chunk. At the end, it's just a matter of changing the length. In fact, you can do it yourself directly: `builder.Length -= 2;`

Answer (score 0):

the code:

```
public string BuildString()
{
    var enumerable = GetEnumerableFromSomewhere();
    var interestingParts = enumerable.Select(v => v.TheInterestingStuff).ToArray();

    stringBuilder.Append("This is it: ");

    foreach(var part in interestingParts)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendPart(part)

    }
    if (stringBuilder.Length>0)
        stringBuilder.Length--;
}

private static void AppendPart(this StringBuilder stringBuilder, InterestingPart part)
{
    if (someCondition(part)) 
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("[{0}] = @{0}", part.Something));         

    }
    else
    {
         stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("[{0}]", part.Something));
         stringBuilder.AppendInFilter(part); //
    }
}
```

much better now IMO.

Now a little discussion on making it very fast. We can use Parallel.For. But you would think (if you would think) the Appends are all happening to a single shareable resource, aka the StringBuilder, and then you would have to lock it to Append to it, not so efficient! Well, if we can say that each iteration of the for loop in the outer function creates one single string artifact, then we can have a single array of string, allocated to the count of interestingParts before the Parallel for starts, and each index of the Parallel for would store its string to its respective index.

Something like:

```
string[] iteration_buckets = new string[interestingParts.Length];
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, interestingParts.Length,
    (index) =>
    {
        iteration_buckets[index] = AppendPart(interestingParts[index]);
    });
```

your function AppendPart will have to be adjusted to make it a non-extension to take just a string and return a string.
After the loop ends you can do a string.Join to get a string, which is what you may be doing with the stringBuilder.ToString() too.